# calculating norm with cut off function

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $\chi$ be a smooth cut-off function, defined on an interval $[0,\infty)$ and it is equal 1 on $[0,X-1)$ and goes to 0 on $[X-1,X)$ then equal 0 on $[X,\infty)$.. Let $v=exp(-ax)$ on $[0,\infty)$..

I need to find the $L^2$-norm of $\chi' v$ and here is my attempt:

$\| \chi' v \|^2=\int_{0}^{\infty} \chi'^2 v^2dx= \int_{X-1}^{X} \chi'^2 exp(-2ax) dx$ ..

Now, how can I finish the calculation because I don't know what is exactly $\chi'$ on $[X-1,X]$ ?
I appreciate any help ..

Comment: Basically you can't! Cut-off functions can be made in a lot of different ways, so the problem is not well posed.

Comment: I don't think that.. cut off are used a lot in situation like this ..

Comment: Yes, but usually to give some esteem.

Comment: Iam thinking about the boundedness of the cutoff function if it can help me in this integration.. the cut off on $[X-1,X]$ is continuous and a continuous function on a bounded set is bounded ..

Comment: For sure $\chi$ and all its derivatives are bounded on $[X-1,X]$, what I mean is that you can't find a precise result in your integration because is not univocal the way you choose the cut-off functions. For instance if $\chi(x)=\phi(x)$ for $x\in[X-1,X]$, you could also define another cut-off $\bar{\chi}$ that equals a "contraction" of $\phi$ in $[X-1,X-1/2]$ and equals $0$ for each $x\geq X-1/2$. The cut-off functions are not equal so you can't expect the integral to be the same.

Comment: Thank you Marco for the clarification.. how about this? $\| \chi ' v \|^2 = \| \chi ' \|^2 \|v\| ^2 $ and find the integration separately for each function and since $\chi$ is bounded then the norm at the end would be $C exp(-aX)$ ?

Comment: Generally $\Vert fg\Vert\ne\Vert f\Vert\Vert g\Vert$.

Comment: but it is less than?

Comment: No, in general. It works if the norm at the l.h.s. is norm 1: $\Vert fg\Vert_1\leq\Vert f\Vert_2\Vert g\Vert_2$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality.

Comment: Thank you Marco..

Comment: You're welcome!